# TransactionScope confusion

Tags: vb.net, transactions

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Transactions

Public Class Form1
    Private _ConString As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand, objCommand2 As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Dim objCon2 As SqlConnection
        Dim id As Integer
        Try
            _ConString = "Data Source=IANSCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2008R2;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
                objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
                objCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PERSON.PERSON WHERE BusinessEntityID<=10")
                objCommand2 = New SqlCommand()
                objCommand.Connection = objCon
                objCommand2.Connection = objCon
                objCon.Open()
                objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader(ConnectionState.Closed)
            Do While objDR.Read
                Using scope As New TransactionScope
                    objCon2 = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
                    objCon2.Open()
                    Using objCon2
                        objCommand2.CommandText = "UPDATE Person.Person SET middlename = @middlename WHERE " & _
                            " Person.BusinessEntityID = @ID "
                        objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", objDR("BusinessEntityID") + 1)
                        objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", objDR("BusinessEntityID"))
                        objCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        objCommand2.Parameters.Clear()
                    End Using
                End Using
            Loop
            objDR.Close() 'line 16
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

In the code above, the Transaction is created for every loop.  The reason I want to do this is because the table is locked until the while loop finishes.  The problem with the code above is that the creation of a transaction is ignored.

Comment: You don't commit your transaction, use [`scope.Complete()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx) for this (right before the `End Using` of your TransactionScope).

Answer (score 0):

1st you don't need to use 2 different SqlCommands variables.
2nd try changing "objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader(ConnectionState.Closed)" to this "objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader()"
3rd try using the scope before the the while loop

Comment: If I put the scope at the beginning (outside the while loop), then it works.  The point is that I want to pit the scope inside the while loop.